# Error development is not defined error with react-hot-loader v3 and webpack-hot-middleware

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, react-hot-loader

Given that these are the dependencies that I am using:

```
"react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
"webpack": "2.6.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.11.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.1",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
```

**Error**

```
patch.js:5 

Uncaught ReferenceError: development is not defined
    at Object.defineProperty.value (patch.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 921586e…:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 921586e…:85)
    at Object.options.path (patch.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 921586e…:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 921586e…:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (process-update.js:132)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 921586e…:659)
    at validateFormat (bootstrap 921586e…:708)
    at bootstrap 921586e…:708
```

You might want to either take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/redux-shoppingcart-fun)
﻿

**webpack-config**

```
const FILE_PATHS = {
  entry: path.resolve('./src/index.js'),
  reactHotLoader: 'react-hot-loader/patch',
  hmrEntry: 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000', // this is from the webpack-hot-middleware docs
  output: '/' // this is the path used by webpack-dev-middleware, the docs say no real path is required, just pass in `/`
}

const devOnly = {
  entry: FILE_PATHS.entry,
  output: {
    path: '/',
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ],
        // react-hot-loader asks to include src and exclude node_modules in https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md
        include: path.resolve('./src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'json-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-sprite-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': 'development'
    })
  ]
}

const hmr = {
  entry: [FILE_PATHS.reactHotLoader, FILE_PATHS.hmrEntry, FILE_PATHS.entry],
  plugins: [new HmrPlugin(), new NoErrorsPlugin()],
  devServer: {
    hot: true
  }
}

const dev = merge(devOnly, hmr)

module.exports = {dev}
```

**Express Server**

```
// process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'
const express = require('express')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback')

const normalizeAssets = assets => {
  return Array.isArray(assets) ? assets : [assets]
}

const getLinks = assets => {
  const styles = assets.filter(path => path.endsWith('.css'))
  const links = styles.map(path => `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${path}" />`)
  return links.join('\n')
}

const publicPath = '/assets/'

const getScripts = assets => {
  const js = assets.filter(path => path.endsWith('.js'))
  const scripts = js.map(path => `<script src="${path}"></script>`)
  return scripts.join('\n')
}

const devMiddlewareConfig = {
  serverSideRender: true,
  stats: 'normal',
  publicPath: publicPath,
  watchOptions: {
    poll: 1000,
    aggregateTimeout: 300
  }
}

const hotMiddlewareConfig = {
  reload: true,
  overlay: true
}

const devMiddlewareCreator = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
const hotMiddlewareCreator = require('webpack-hot-middleware')

const options = require('./webpack.config')

const {dev: devConfig} = options

const compiler = webpack(devConfig)
const devMiddleware = devMiddlewareCreator(compiler, devMiddlewareConfig)
const hotMiddleware = hotMiddlewareCreator(compiler, hotMiddlewareConfig)

const app = express()
app.use(devMiddleware)
app.use(hotMiddleware)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use((req, res) => {
  const stats = res.locals.webpackStats.toJson()
  const assets = normalizeAssets(stats.assetsByChunkName.main)
  const styles = getLinks(assets)
  const scripts = getScripts(assets)
  res.send(
    `
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Webpack is crazy</title>
        ${styles}
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="app">
      </div>
      ${scripts}
      </body>
    </html>
`
  )
})

// app.use(historyApiFallback)

app.listen(3000, err => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 3000')
  }
})
```

Comment: Did you mean `'development': 'process.env.NODE_ENV'`?

Comment: @AndrewLi where do you mean?

Comment: In your config, in `new DefinePlugin({ … })`

Comment: @AndrewLi I just got it working but it wont do HMR properly, I manually added the `DefinePlugin` to the hmr config instead of adding it using webpack-merge. I do not understand why it works and I do not yet have faith that it will continue working.

Comment: No, let my share it in gist https://gist.github.com/vamsiampolu/57c0a6faa294a98a5500c4806f9c58f0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is caused by this part of your configuration:

```
new DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': 'development'
})
```

To quote [the documentation:](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

> Note that because the plugin does a direct text replacement, the value given to it must include actual quotes inside of the string itself. Typically, this is done either with either alternate quotes, such as '"production"', or by using JSON.stringify('production').

If you replace it with, for example, the following, it should work:

```
new DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"'
})
```